# Convert Canvas to image then download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to convert a section of my site into a downloadable image.

Firstly I convert the html to a canvas using:

```
$(function() { 
$("#download").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#the-grid"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            $("#saved").append(canvas);
            $("#saved canvas").attr('id', 'scan');          
        }           
    });
```

Which works fine the canvas get generated and all look's good.

I then want to turn that into an image which I can use for thumbnails later but also initiate a download of the image.

To do so I complete the function like this.

```
$(function() { 
$("#download").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($("#the-grid"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            $("#saved").append(canvas);
            $("#saved canvas").attr('id', 'scan');
            var c=document.getElementById("scan");
            var d=c.toDataURL("image/png");
            var w=window.open('about:blank','Download Mix');
            w.document.write("<img src='"+d+"' alt='Custom Blend'/>");
        }

    });
```

But it doesn't work.

The error's I get are totally irrelevant.

I am an experienced developer but I'm pretty new to Jquery so any help would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

Got it to work.

Create image like this

```
$(function () {
    $("#download").click(function () {
        html2canvas($("#the-grid"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                $("#saved").append(canvas);
                $("#saved canvas").attr('id', 'scan');
                var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $("#saved").append("<img src='"+image+"' alt='Custom Blend'/>");
            }

        });
```

image html ends up looking like

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..." alt="Custom Blend">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you :

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); // build url of the image
window.location.href=image; //activate download
image = "<img src='"+image+"'/>"; // set canvas image as source
```

Comment: That does kick in the download only problem is it doesn't try to make it a png it comes in as just a file.

Comment: can you try like this without replacing mime type ?
    `var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

Comment: pop's up a new window with the image instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did this (note, there's no way to download a file in Safari and set the filename without pinging a server):

First, you need to get the canvas as a png: `var img = canvas.toDataUrl('image/png');`

Then, you'll want to convert that dataURL to a blob. For a good way to do that, see [this](https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js/blob/master/src/filer.js#L137) function.

Now you want to download that blob. This will work in all browsers but Safari:

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
  window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'image.png');
} else {
  var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var objectURL = url.createObjectURL(blob);
  var ele = $('<a target="_blank"></a>')
              .hide()
              .attr('download', 'image.png')
              .attr('href', objectURL);
  $('body').append(ele);
  var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': false,
  });
  ele[0].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    url.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
    ele.remove();
  }, 1000);
}
```

This creates an invisible link and simulates a click on it. The `click()` function won't work in Firefox, so you have to create an event and dispatch it by hand. Finally, it does a bit of clean up by removing the invisible link after one second. In IE, it uses the method provided by Microsoft. This will download the image with the filename "image.png". It also has the benefit of being able to download any blob, if you need to be able to do more with your code. Hopefully this helps!